# Why react hot loader only works for hot(module)(App) and resets reducer state in others?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-hot-loader

I've had pretty old dependencies in my project, so I decided to update all of them. The problem I faced was related to React hot loader. Now hot-loading works fine with my App component which I decorate with hot(module)(App). In other components/routes hot-loading works, but resets all reducers' states, as a result the web app redirects to Login page because `auth` prop is reset and never changed.

App component:

```
class App extends Component {
  state={
    loggedIn:false,
    state1:false,
    state2:false,
    state3:false,

  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    console.log('apploggedIn', this.props.loggedIn, prevProps.loggedIn)
    this.props.loggedIn!==prevProps.loggedIn&&this.setState({loggedIn:this.props.loggedIn})

  }
  componentDidMount() {

     // console.log('didmount', this.props)
    this.props.token&&this.props.dispatch(actions.getAttornies(this.props.token))
    this.props.token&&this.props.dispatch(actions.getProviderList(this.props.token)) 




  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(actions.isLoggedIn())

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

    console.log('nextprops',nextProps)
    if (this.props.token!==nextProps.token) {
      nextProps.token&&nextProps.dispatch(actions.getAttornies(nextProps.token))
      nextProps.token&&nextProps.dispatch(actions.getProviderList(nextProps.token))

    }

  }
  onUnload(){
    this.props.router.push('/')
  }

  onLogin(e) {
    this.props.dispatch(actions.signIn(e.login,e.password))
  }
  render() {
    const { location, children, dispatch, loggedIn, alert } = this.props;
    console.log("AppProps", this.props)


          return <div className="vbox container-fluid">

            <div className="row">
                <section className="hbox stretch" style={{width:'100%', background:'#f3f4f8'}}>

                    <section id="content">
                      <Header
                          router={this.props.history}
                          dispatch={this.props.dispatch}
                          openModal={(e)=>this.openModal(e)}/>

                      <div className="row"
                      >
                      <div className="col-12" style={{minHeight:'90vh'}}>
                        <Switch>
                          <PrivateRoute exact path="/"  component={Startpage} />
                          <Route
                              component={PatientSearch}
                              path="/patient/search"
                          />

                          <PrivateRoute
                              component={Technician}
                              path="/technician"
                          />
                          <Route
                              component={Login}
                              path="/login"
                          />
                          <Route
                              component={Analytics}
                              path="/analytics"
                          />

                          <Route
                              component={Notes}
                              path="/notes"
                          />

                          <Route
                              component={DeliveryReports}
                              path="/delivery_reports"
                          />

                        </Switch>
                      </div>

                      </div>

                    </section>
                </section>
            </div>
          </div>

      }      

  // }
}

const mapStateToProps=(state)=>{
  return {
    loggedIn: state.app.loggedIn,
    token: state.app.token,
    isLoading: state.loading.loading,
    alert:state.alert
  };
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(hot(module)(App)));
```

Root component:

```
const store = configureStore(/* provide initial state if any */)

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, authed, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
        authed === true
            ? <Component {...props} />
            : <Redirect to={{
              pathname: '/login',
              state: { from: props }
            }} />
    )} />
)

class Root extends Component {
  state = {loggedIn:false}




  render() {

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
          <Router >
            <App>

            </App>


          </Router>
        </ConnectedRouter>
       </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default (Root)
```

Least level component index.js

```
import "babel-polyfill";
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Root from './containers/Root';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore'
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';
const store = configureStore();


const render = Component => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <AppContainer>
      <Component />
    </AppContainer>,
    document.getElementById('wrapperContainer'),
  );
};

render(Root)

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./containers/Root', () => {
    const NextRootContainer = require('./containers/Root').default;
    render(NextRootContainer);
  });
}
```

Configure store part:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers, compose } from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import { connectRouter } from 'connected-react-router'

import promiseMiddleware from '../middleware/promiseMiddleware';
import loggerMiddleware from 'redux-logger';
import * as reducers from '../reducers/';
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form'
import app from '../reducers/app'
import {createBrowserHistory} from "history";

export const history = createBrowserHistory()
const reducer = combineReducers({...reducers.default, router:connectRouter(history), form:formReducer });
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(
    thunkMiddleware,
    promiseMiddleware
)(createStore);

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
    const store =  createStoreWithMiddleware(
        reducer,
        initialState,
        window.devToolsExtension && window.devToolsExtension()
    );
    if (module.hot) {
        module.hot.accept('../reducers', () => {
            const nextRootReducer = require('../reducers/index').default
            store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer);
        });
    }
    return store;
}
```

I'm really sorry for flooding with so much code, but I really do not know what is wrong here.

Comment: Related issue including pointers to the answer: https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/1266#issuecomment-501142821

Answer (score 0):

- The minimal React-Hot-loader version with hook hot-reloading support - **4.9.0**, anything below will not update them **at all**(except the cases then effect has to be re-run).
- The minimal React-Hot-loader version with hook reordering support - **4.11.0**, anything below will throw if you add/remove or move hook.

As you've mentioned in a RHL's ticket - you are using 4.3.0.

Comment: Updated but it didn't help unfortunately